# Why is getInitialState getting called again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am finding my way into react.js and having trouble figuring out why `getInitialState` is being called once more than I would expect. I am trying to write a component that shows some value as a label and can be switched to edit that value by presenting an input text, together with ways to save or cancel the edit operation.

Here's the component:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;

var ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13;

var TextInput = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    id: ReactPropTypes.string,
    className: ReactPropTypes.string,
    placeholder: ReactPropTypes.string,
    onSave: ReactPropTypes.func.isRequired,
    initialValue: ReactPropTypes.string
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      value: this.props.initialValue,
      isEditing: false
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    var inputField = 
    (<div>
      <input
          className={this.props.className}
          id={this.props.id}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          onBlur={this._save}
          onChange={this._onChange}
          onKeyDown={this._onKeyDown}
          value={this.state.value}
          autoFocus={true}
        />
      <a onClick={this._save}>(s)</a>
      <a onClick={this._cancel}>(x)</a>
    </div>);
    var displayField =
      (<div>
        <span>{this.state.value}</span>
        <a href='#' onClick={this._startEdit}>(e)</a>
      </div>);

    return this.state.isEditing ? inputField : displayField;
  },

  _startEdit: function() {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value,
      fallBackValue: this.props.initialValue,
      isEditing: true
    });
  },

  _save: function() {
    this.props.onSave({ id: this.props.id, value: this.state.value });
    this.setState({
      isEditing: false
    });
  },
  _cancel: function() {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: false,
      value: this.state.fallBackValue
    });
  },
  _onChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: true,
      value: event.target.value,
      fallBackValue: this.state.fallBackValue
    });
  },
  _onKeyDown: function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY_CODE) {
      this._save();
    }
  }

});

module.exports = TextInput;
```

Once I press (e)dit, I shortly see the input box only to be replaced again by the span - as I can see in the debugger `getInitialState` gets called again, switching the component back to a non-edit state.

Where is my thinking error, as I would have expected `getInitialState` to only be called once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out - http://jsbin.com/tixokayoke/1/ the missing href in the anchor tag is causing the issue for you. Without the href the page is being re-requested and the state being reset again.

Comment: True! I think I'll make a mini-repro. Granted, an a without href is silly but the resulting behavior is pretty strange.